# What subclasses of `Profunctor` does `FunList` support?

Tags: haskell, category-theory, traversable

A `FunList` is a datatype invented by Twan van Laarhoven in [this blog post](https://twanvl.nl/blog/haskell/non-regular1). A minor variation [given by Bartosz Milewski](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2018/10/12/trading-funlists-at-a-bazaar-with-yoneda/) looks like this:

```
data FunList a b t = Done t 
                   | More a (FunList a b (b -> t))
```

An interesting fact about this datatype is that if we shuffle around the type parameters a bit, we have a `Profunctor`:

```
data FunList t b a
  = Done t 
  | More a (FunList (b -> t) b a)

mapResult :: (a -> b) -> FunList a x y -> FunList b x y
mapResult f (Done x)   = Done $ f x
mapResult f (More a r) = More a $ mapResult (f .) r

instance Profunctor (FunList t)
  where
  dimap _ _ (Done t) = Done t
  dimap f g (More a r) = More (g a) $ dimap f g $ mapResult (. f) r
```

Obeying `dimap id id = id` and `dimap (f . g) (h . i) = dimap g h . dimap f i`

The class `Profunctor` has several useful subclasses that represent families of profunctors (in the category theory sense) with additional equipment. Specifically, we can talk about profunctors with a "strength":

```
class Profunctor p => Strong t1 t2 p
  where
  pstrength :: p a b -> p (t1 a x) (t2 b x)
```

With laws dictated by the categorical notion of a "strong monad in a bicategory" (this is explained in detail in ["Arrows are Strong Monads"](https://www.riec.tohoku.ac.jp/%7Easada/papers/arrStrMnd.pdf) by Kazuyuki Asada).

Similarly, since profunctors are "just" functors, we can look for whether a profunctor is monoidal:

```
class Profunctor p => SemigroupalProfunctor t1 t2 t3 p
  where
  combine :: t3 (p a b) (p c d) -> p (t1 a c) (t2 b d)

class SemigroupalProfunctor t1 t2 t3 p => MonoidalProfunctor t1 i1 t2 i2 t3 i3 p
  where
  unit :: i3 -> p i1 i2
```

With laws given by the definition of a monoidal functor.

Some interesting choices for `t1`, `t2`, `t3` and `i1`, `i2`, `i3` are `(,)`, `Either`, `These` and `()` and `Void` respectively.

The question is which such classes does the reshuffled `FunList` instantiate? An implementation with some argument as to why it follows the laws would be very good, a proof of correctness would be excellent.

TODO: Specialize out list of laws for each class here

Comment: This seems like a question you could go a long ways toward answering yourself by attempting to implement `pstrength`, `combine`, and `unit` yourself. Any problems you have implementing *one* of them would make for a good question.

Comment: @chepner This is true, but as a single person I have a limited amount of time and expertise (e.g. right now I have next to no time, and don't want to just discard this question). I think the promise of Stack Overflow is that we can provide a forum for collecting answers to an interesting question that draws on the expertise of many people.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: I think you’ll get a better discussion if you post this on https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell